# MVC 5 all requests get routed to account/login despite AllowAnonymous

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

In our webapplication we implmented cookieauthentitcation:

```
   app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
```

In the account login the class is decorated with the [Authorize] tag and the [AllowAnonymouse] tag. This works, the Login page is accessible.

I added an other page and I also decorated this page with an [Authorize] and [AllowAnonymouse] tag combination. But for some reason I get routed to my login page.

We use ASP.NET mvc 5, together with castle windsor as dep installer. My filter looks like:

```
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    }
```

For some reason it all non /account/login pages get routed to /account/login if not logged in. This behaviour is caused by LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"). Is there a way to only route to login if authentication requires it?

Comment: why are you adding an authorize attribute if anonymous access is allowed?

Comment: Due to the fact that I read it was needed. Tried without gave no result.

Answer (score 1):

Found the actual problem. A partial view that was included (navigation) had an authorize attribute on it. That was causing the redirect to the login page.